# Difficulty installing combinatorics module on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos

I attempted to run the program that plays mastermind, here:
http://www.python-course.eu/mastermind.php

To do so, I installed python3.4.3 first.

I ran the program, but it returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mastermind_p1_trim.py", line 5, in <module>
    from combinatorics import all_colours
ImportError: No module named 'combinatorics'
```

So I navigated to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Combinatorics

and downloaded it, then ran python3

```
python3 setup.py install
```

from within the Directory downloaded.

This returned

```
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Combinatorics-1.4.5-py3.4.egg-info
```

finally, sys.path returns

['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

when running python3.

So, I do not know why I am still receiving the error,

```
ImportError: No module named 'combinatorics'
```

I have looked at other similar pages on SO, but the suggestions there do not seems to solve my problem. Could anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinatorics might not be compatible with `Python 3.4.3`

Here are some suggestions:

- Un-install Python 3.4.3 and all it's resources
- Install `python 2.7`
- Install `combinatorics`

[Read more in detail](https://code.activestate.com/pypm/combinatorics/)

**Here is a guide from ActiveState:**

> 1. Download and install [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads#)
> 2. [IGNORE THIS] Buy and install the Business Edition license from account.activestate.com
> 3. Open Command Prompt
> 4. Type `pypm install combinatorics`

Comment: The author of the program specifies that you need to run python3 at the URL given

Comment: @VincentLaufer that's odd, the link I provided says otherwise.

Comment: You're right it ... certainly does. I went ahead and ran `sudo python setup.py install` to install it for python2.7 then ran the script. I got a similar issue, it says, "ImportError: No module named combinatorics"

Comment: @VincentLaufer have you tried installing with `pypm`

Comment: @VincentLaufer please have a look at the edited answer, hope it helps.

Comment: after completing that procedure, I still receive python mastermind_p1_trim.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mastermind_p1_trim.py", line 8, in <module>
    from combinatorics import all_colours
ImportError: No module named combinatorics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79686/discussion-between-vincent-laufer-and-nazmul).